# How to make the arrow point down when card is closed and to rotate on first click without jquery or javascript?

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I have a setup and can't figure it out how to make the arrow work

I made it so that it rotates and all is fine if a card is opened, but when the card is closed then on first click it doesn't do anything... which is ok I think.

But how can I set the arrow to point down when the card is closed?

https://jsfiddle.net/b7msn10u/12/

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div  class="card-header">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-example">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up pull-right"></i>
                On first click icon doesn't rotate 
            </a>
        </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-example">
          <div class="card-block">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda itaque asperiores sapiente aut debitis nulla accusantium odit voluptate minima eos quia animi numquam quo atque, saepe autem tempora, reprehenderit facere?
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>

    <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-example">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up pull-right"></i>
                Here it does rotate on first click
            </a>
        </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse2" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading-example">
          <div class="card-block p-3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda itaque asperiores sapiente aut debitis nulla accusantium odit voluptate minima eos quia animi numquam quo atque, saepe autem tempora, reprehenderit facere?
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <h3 class="mt-3">How to make the arrow point down when card is closed and to rotate on first click?</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **collapsed** element is tricky to setup; besides [all the other attributes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/) - can be digested to this main attributes differences:

---

## Closed (collapsed)

To make a pair (button + element) "closed" *(collapsed)* you need also this attributes:

**BUTTON**

- `class="collapsed"`  **you're missing this class**
- `aria-expanded="false"` **set to false**, since it's collapsed...
- `aria-controls="collapse1"` fix this one to the right selectors

**ELEMENT**

- `class="collapse"`

And use an UP pointing arrow but rotated 180° with CSS using the `.collapsed` as reference

```
.card-header .fa-chevron-up {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.card-header .collapsed .fa-chevron-up {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

---

## Open (Uncollapsed)

To make a pair (button + element) "open" *(uncollapsed)* you need to:

**BUTTON**

- `class=""`  No class needed
- `aria-expanded="true"`  Set to true

**ELEMENT**

- `class="collapse show"`

EXAMPLE:

```css
.card-header .fa-chevron-up {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.card-header .collapsed .fa-chevron-up {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<br />
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div  class="card-header">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-up pull-right"></i>
              On first click icon doesn't rotate 
            </a>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-example">
          <div class="card-block">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda itaque asperiores sapiente aut debitis nulla accusantium odit voluptate minima eos quia animi numquam quo atque, saepe autem tempora, reprehenderit facere?
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse2">
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-up pull-right"></i>
              Here it does rotate on first click
            </a>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse2" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading-example">
          <div class="card-block p-3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda itaque asperiores sapiente aut debitis nulla accusantium odit voluptate minima eos quia animi numquam quo atque, saepe autem tempora, reprehenderit facere?
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <h3 class="mt-3">How to make the arrow point down when card is closed and to rotate on first click?</h3>
</div>
```

> Basically it's a logic mess. No wonder many people get confused. But that's Bootstrap. ...